# How to store a list of words to disk

Tags: database, performance, python-3.x, sqlite, pickle

I need to analyze files which returns a long list of words back. What would be an efficient way of storing this list for retrieving at another time? I could probably pickle out a file for each input file, but that might be messy if there are 1000's of input files.

```
def analyze_file(input_file):
    big_list = list()
    # Do something and create a big list of words from the input_file
    return big_list

for a_file in file_list:
    my_list = analyze_file(a_file)
    # Store this list to disk for retrieval
```

Also what type is the most efficient to convert to (json, pickle, etc)

Comment: See http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html.